# Override virtual method with static method

Tags: c++

Is there any specific reason why I cannot override virtual method from base class with static one?
Anyone knows why it would be bad idea?

Example:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

class Foo
{
public:
    virtual void SomeMethod() = 0;
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
    static void SomeMethod() override
    {
        printf("SomeMethod");
    }
};

void SomeFunctionWithFoo( Foo *p )
{
    p->SomeMethod();
}

int main()
{
    Bar o;

    o.SomeMethod();
    SomeFunctionWithFoo( &o );
    Bar::SomeMethod();
    o.StaticSomeMethod();
}
```

Instead I have to do this:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

class Foo
{
public:
    virtual void SomeMethod() = 0;
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
    void SomeMethod() override
    {
        StaticSomeMethod();
    }

    static void StaticSomeMethod()
    {
        printf("SomeMethod");
    }
};

void SomeFunctionWithFoo( Foo *p )
{
    p->SomeMethod();
}

int main()
{
    Bar o;

    o.SomeMethod();
    SomeFunctionWithFoo( &o );
    Bar::StaticSomeMethod();
    o.StaticSomeMethod();
}
```

I think as long as you don't need to access member variables, your function can be static, so that it can serve behaviour without object. In the same time such static function can serve behaviour when using interface. But maybe I am wrong and I am missing something?

With one method and two classes, it is not problem, but I have case of 10 such methods inside class, and many classes that inherit.

In real world scenario, such possibility would make my code simpler.

Comment: `static` and `virtual` are mutually exclusive and cannot be used together

Comment: What if the base virtual method is const?  Does that mean that your static method must be const?  By your understanding, ALL static methods are technically const, so it should "work".  What if I have 2 pure virtual methods in the base, one const, one non-const.  Can both be overridden with the same static method?  What if I wanted them to be 2 different static methods?

Comment: @franji1 Actually that is very good point. I think in this case, static method would override both of the methods. And if you don't want to do that, you don't provide static method override, but instead two non-static methods override (const & non-const).

Answer (score 0):

Summary: member functions have an invisible first parameter that your static method doesn't have.

Details: Member functions (effectively) are effectively all static methods that have an "invisible" first parameter, which is the `Bar* this` parameter, which tells the method which instance of the class to use. So the signature of `virtual void SomeMethod()` is, under the covers, actually `static void SomeMethod(Foo*)`, but `static StaticSomeMethod()` doesn't have the same number of parameters.

C++ is *mostly* able to pretend this parameter doesn't exist, but overrides are one case where it pops up. You also see it occur when trying to bind a member function to a `std::function`, where you have to explicitly pass the `this` as the first pointer.

Comment: I have thought about this, and it should not be problem. That is: compiler should generate two versions of `static void SomeMethod() override`: first real one, static, no hidden parameter, with actual code, second one, as call to static function (first one) and having hidden parameter. It is not big deal for compiler I think.

Comment: That would require a very minor change in the C++ spec, but you're right that it's a viable and reasonable change.

Comment: No, that's entirely unreasonable suggestion. With `struct Foo:public Baz{static void bar() override;};`, what would be the result of `&Foo::bar`? Member function or static function? Which one should be pointed to in vtable? What about `decltype(&Foo::bar)`? Can `Foo::bar` decay to pointer or not? Can it be `const` member function? Can I choose which one I actually want to call with any syntax? If yes, which one is called with `this->Foo::bar()`?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen C++ already says that `&Foo::bar` gets the virtual method even if there's an implementation, (this already happens for destructors for instance) so that's actually already solved. Same with `decltype(&Foo::bar)` and pointer decay and `const`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Proof that `&Base::foo` already points to virtual, even when it already has an implementation: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a99146e08e35152d. I vaguely recall there's a way to get a pointer to the non-virtual implementation of an overridden virtual method, but can't recall the syntax right now

Comment: Oh, maybe what I was remembering was that `&Base::foo` outside of `Derived` implementation refers to the virtual method, but `&Base::foo` *within* a `Derived` implementation refers to the non-virtual method. Or something like that?

Comment: Keep in mind, that `&Base::foo` is not valid argument in discussion. Because you can have multiple functions with the same name, but different arguments. Then `&Base::foo` does not work, unless you provide function signature. And if you provide function signature, then case with static function override, is also solved. (https://godbolt.org/z/j1n1E46vc & https://godbolt.org/z/ePKnPo6cG)

Comment: And to not brake backwards compatibility, if there is only one variant of `&Foo::bar` then virtual method should be picked by compiler.